# Flask returning some response objects as string-like JSON not JSON

Tags: python, json, flask

I have five variables I am trying to return from a flask route. Seemingly no matter how I format them, two of them will NOT return as anything but JSON-looking strings.

My Flask route looks like this

```
@app.route('/mapcreator/<lat>/<lng>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def receive_coords(lat, lng):
    lat = float(lat)
    lng = float(lng)
    point = (lat,lng)
    map1 = somefunction(point)
    number = ((somefunction(point))[0])
    featureCount = ((somefunction(point))[1])
    map2 = ((amb.somefunction(point))[2])
    response = make_response(jsonify(map1=map1, number=number, featureCount=featureCount, map2=map2, point=point))
    response.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json'
    return response
```

number, point, map1 are returning correctly as json objects.
Each variable's Type in Python:

- number: int
- point: array
- map1: dict
- map2: str
- featureCount: str

This is how each of the variables is processed in the backend:

- map1: `map1back = mplleaflet.fig_to_geojson(fig=ax.figure)` prints as a geojson, looks like a dict
- map2: `map2back = df_to_geojson(poi_df, col); map2back = json.dumps(poiGJ)`

looks like a standard geojson

- featureCount:
  `featureCount = all_features['feature'].value_counts(); featureCount = featureCount.to_json()`

looks like a standard json

If I change the type of these to dict, I get

> 500 internal server error.

As everything stands they log in the browser console like this:

```
featureCount:"{"parking":67,"bicycle_parking":32,"bench":20,"p.....

map2:"{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coo.....
```

They do not read as "Object > " but rather as JSON-looking strings.

I have tried everything here and I am really stumped. I can't see anything different about these two response objects and I cannot get them to be real JSON responses.

Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

```
response = make_response(jsonify(map1=map1, number=number, 
featureCount=json.loads(featureCount), 
map2=json.loads(map2), point=point))
```

Had to do with the jsons being json like strings rather than JSON objects. Pandas only creates json style strings.